# How to get checkbox inside table row cell

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I'm very noob in javascript.

I'm trying to alert the id of a checkbox inside table view row cell.

I tried:

```
var checkBox = grid.rows[i].cells[0].firstChild;
alert(checkBox.id);
```

but the alert box shows "undefined".

Comment: Could you include your HTML? It is easier to find the problem then.

Comment: It's asp.net page, and I'm using javascript to toggle all checkboxes inside DataGridView, I already done it by getting all inputs inside the dataGrid then checking the type of the input and finally change the checked property, but I'm trying another ways for learning sake only.

Comment: The problem is that `checkBox`is undefined. What is `i`?

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer, instead of using

```
grid.rows[i].cells[0].firstChild
```

I tried

```
grid.rows[i].cells[0].children[0]
```

and it works perfectly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
function check() {
    let table = $('#tableId').DataTable();
    let rows = table.rows({selected: true}).nodes().to$();
    var checkBox = rows[0].cells[0].children[0];
    alert(checkBox.id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery, and do something like this: 
    `

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//alert();
$(".chk").bind("click",function(){
          alert($(this).attr("id"));
          //alert();
    });
});
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <form action="">
        <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="one" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="two" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
</form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Give id to Check box

```
    <input type='checkbox' id='chkbox1' name='ex1_b'>

    var checkbox = $('#chkbox1');    

    alert(checkbox.attr('id'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var table = document.getElementById("tblRestaurantTiming");

        //Loop through Table Rows.
        for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length - 1; i++) {
            //Reference the Table Row.
            var row = table.rows[i];   
            var lastorder = row.cells[6].firstChild;
            var check = lastorder.checked;
           }
```